# How should I perform tree traversal in given structure?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tree

## Mission

I'm trying to find out the count of children in a set of tables illustrated below. The environment is LAMP but help in the right direction via other syntaxes are appreciated.

### Table structure

```
users
-----
user_id  
parent_id


user_meta
---------
user_id
registration_date


user_levels
-----------
user_id
level
```

This basic structure is unlikely to change but could be extended.

### Use case

```
select
  users.user_id
from
  users
inner join
  user_meta
  on users.user_id = user_meta.user_id
inner join
  user_levels
  on users.user_id = user_levels.user_id
where
  parent_id = *x*
  and
  registration_date > *certain date*
  and
  level < *certain level*
```

### Conditions

- A user's descendant only counts as such if its level is lower than given `*certain level*`. If descendant's level is not lower, the node is a leaf but should be excluded from the count.
- Given `*certain level*` and `*certain date*` are the same for every query/set of queries.

I've tried using this in a loop but the amount of queries quickly escalades. This solution could probably be used and stored in a cron job but I'd prefer an as-real-time-as-it-gets-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current data model there isn't a more efficient way to do it than recursively querying the database. If you are able to change the way the data is stored to include more information you can use the Modified Preorder Tree Traversal (also refered to as the Nested set model). This model is discussed in an article on the [MySQL website](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). There are also many examples on this website, just search for "Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal".

Comment: If I could, I would make some modifications to the model but it's a too demanding task to acheive this goal, sadly. I would recommend your answer to anyone building a hierarchal database from scratch though, so +1 (and thanks for an official name).

Answer (score 0):

It might be faster to pull all of the user records into local memory and run an algorithm there instead, depending on how many users you have. SQL isn't really suited for recursive tree traversal.

Comment: The `users` table is pretty huge, so it couldn't be done on request but perhaps in a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL99 feature witch is called "Common Table Expression" wich allow you to create recurcive functions and efficiently handle hierarchical data stored in relational database.

It looks like MySql does not (yet) implement it but you could see what can be done with this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx

Comment: I'm having trouble translating your reference to a MySQL-enviroment but I figure it's a benefit I can't take part of. Thanks for your answer though, and feel free to elaborate if you know how it could be translated to MySQL.